# Script to append timestamp prefix to variable

Tags: scripting-language, thunar

I've got a Thunar script with this only line:
cp "$@" "$@-$TS".txt
it appends a timestamp suffix and the .txt extension to the file I right-click in

Now, I want to append a timestamp prefix and also add the .txt extension, but it doesn't work:
cp "$@" "$TS-$@".txt

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This also appends a timestamp suffix to the filename: cp $1 $1_$(date +"%d-%b-%Y_%H:%M:%S").txt  But, when I try to put the timestamp as a prefix, it doesn't work either:  cp $1 "$(date +"%d-%b-%Y_%H:%M:%S")"_"$1".txt

Comment: Found a very good solution here: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found a solution.
Replace geany with your favourite text editor.

```
#!/bin/sh
TS=$( date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S )
cp "$@" $TS.txt
geany $TS.txt
```